# Unable to log in to ubuntu after failing to move home partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I was on Windows (dual boot) and tried to move the home partition using the MiniTool Partition Wizard. After cancelling the operation (it got stuck in 100% for a while) the home partition became unrecognizable and the file system of it turned from ext4 to another. May I know what should I do to recover this partition? I am able to boot into Ubuntu, but if I try to log in to it, it only returns to the same login screen.

MiniTool Partition Wizard:

[image: A screenshot about the partition in MiniTool partition wizard]

Comment: It is never a good idea to manipulate an Ubuntu partition using tools from Windows.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. If I want to access the files in the partition, what could I do? There is not much important data in ubuntu except for the bookmarks I have in firefox.

Comment: Something like [this may help](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/fsck-command-linux). Try booting Ubuntu from the Live USB and use the **Try Ubuntu** option. Then try to fix the partition.